# Re-using same code for navigationbar items in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, navigationbar, tabview, swiftui-navigationstack, navigationbaritems

I'm setting up an SwiftUI app with TabView-navigation and individual NavigationStacks (to preserve individual navigation state per stack).

One thing that buggles my mind is that I want to have the same profile button in the top right navigationbar on every View. Adding the navigationbar item as below requires me to have the exact same code/addition in every View.

```
.navigationDestination(isPresented: $presentProfilePage) {
    ProfileView()
}
.toolbar {
    Button {
        presentProfilePage = true
    } label: {
        if let img = user.displayImg {
            Image(uiImage: img)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 48, height: 48)
        } else {
            Image.defaultProfileImage
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to set the navigationbar items once and then they are visible on all views?

Comment: But the button in a ViewModifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this code in a `ViewModifier`. You can put `presentProfilePage` as a `@State` in there.

```
struct ProfileNavigation: ViewModifier {
    @State var presentProfilePage = false
    let image: UIImage?
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .navigationDestination(isPresented: $presentProfilePage) {
                ProfileView()
            }
            .toolbar {
                Button {
                    presentProfilePage = true
                } label: {
                    if let image {
                        Image(uiImage: image)
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 48, height: 48)
                    } else {
                        Image.defaultProfileImage
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}

extension View {
    func profileNavigation(image: UIImage?) -> some View {
        modifier(ProfileNavigation(image: image))
    }
}
```

You'd just add `.profileNavigation(...)` to each view you want to have this button.

Alternatively, you can use a `NavigationLink` in the `toolbar` directly. You would just extract the `NavigationLink` as a `View` to reuse it:

```
struct ProfileNavigation: View {
    let image: UIImage?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink {
            ProfileView()
        } label: {
            if let image {
                Image(uiImage: image)
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 48, height: 48)
            } else {
                Image.defaultProfileImage
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
.toolbar {
    ProfileNavigation(...)
}
```